# Stratification vs. Adjusting in Survival Analysis

Tags: survival

Suppose you want to compare survival of males and females within three groups. What is the difference between performing a log-rank test for each group (stratification) vs adjusting for it? Does the stratification allow for the survival curves in each group to differ?